# Unused or misunderstood trait usage in Catalog/Controller/Product.php?

Tags: magento2, product, php, catalog, model

In the `Magento\module-catalog\Controller\Product.php` file there is a line:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ModelProduct;
```

I see no reference to the Product model in the code and none of the functions seem to be used from the model file. Am I missing something or is this trait call redundant?

```
<?php
/**
 * Product controller.
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Controller;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\ViewInterface;
***
```

> use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ModelProduct;

---

```
abstract class Product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements ViewInterface
{
    /**
     * Initialize requested product object
     *
     * @return ModelProduct
     */
    protected function _initProduct()
    {
        $categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
        $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $product */
        $product = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product');
        return $product->initProduct($productId, $this, $params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is **used in the PHPDoc block of the `_initProduct` method**:

```
/**
 * Initialize requested product object
 *
 * @return ModelProduct
 */
```

On top of that, when you click the `initProduct` return line:

```
return $product->initProduct($productId, $this, $params);
```

**Your IDE will open the `initProduct` method** defined in the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` class.

Comment: May I ask why it's used in the PHPDoc block?

Comment: @LM_Fielding well that's the purpose of the PHPDoc block right ? In that case it is to document what kind of object will be returned from this method.

Comment: So the trait is being included but it has no functionality in that file? If I removed the line would anything break?

Comment: @LM_Fielding yes you're right. you can remove the line if you want but I suggest you do not edit core files as changes will be overriden during upgrades

Comment: Of course, just my way of falsifying.

Comment: It's not a trait, it's an aliased class import.

Comment: @fschmengler yep 100%